# html - controlling how many options show in a select element

Tags: html, css, xhtml, select, drop-down-menu

So I have a drop down (select) element. The problem is that if there is a long list in it, then it "drops" upwards instead of downwards.

Is there a way to say that it should scroll rather than show all of them at once?

I know there's "size" but that's how many are visible at once (I only want one visible, like normal)

Or is the reason it's not having a scrollbar automatically caused by it's containing div? Does it need to know where it should end or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this works is up to the browser. Nothing you can do about it, other than building your own drop-down with JS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the list size, it drops upwards or downwards according the size above or below to always show the entire list if possible. It's a comprehensive behaviour and I don't think (and I don't want) you can change it.